# VB.Net DataGridView will accept numeric values only in edit mode

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

One particular cell in my datagridview will accept numeric only on edit mode.
What I want is if they leave the cell empty or 0 it will automatically change to value 1.

Here is my code below:

```
Private Sub dgvPrint_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgvPrint.EditingControlShowing
    Dim txtEdit As TextBox = e.Control

    RemoveHandler txtEdit.KeyPress, AddressOf CopiesText_KeyPress
    AddHandler txtEdit.KeyPress, AddressOf CopiesText_KeyPress
End Sub



Private Sub CopiesText_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles CopiesText.KeyPress

    If dgvPrint.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 5 Then
        If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar.ToString()) Or e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
            e.Handled = False
        Else
            e.Handled = True
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input." & vbCrLf & "Please enter numeric value.", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe with the focus lost event you can do a similar checking to what you already did, you put the on focus lost, check if its the column 5 and look if the cell value is = 0 or = "" then assign that cell a value of 1

Comment: The `CellEndEdit` seems the most likely place to address this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your ideas guys. What I did is

```
Private Sub dgvPrint_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvPrint.CellEndEdit
    For X = 0 To dgvPrint.Rows.Count - 1
        If Val(dgvPrint.Rows(X).Cells("dgvcCopies").Value) = 0 Then
            dgvPrint.Rows(X).Cells("dgvcCopies").Value = 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It's working But I dont know if this is the right code to do.